# Do any other Enterprises have locations named in a similar way to 'Ten Forward?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

The question [Does the name Ten Forward have any precedent in the real world or in fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260980/does-the-name-ten-forward-have-any-precedent-in-the-real-world-or-in-fiction/260993) and the current answer show how locations on the enterprise match present day naval making schemes:

> Sometimes ship areas have actual names (the Promenade), and sometimes their names are simply the description of their location (just like, Town Center, or The Green). So 7 Fwd, 6 Aft, etc, can all be used as locations on a ship.

Besides 'Ten Forward' on the NCC-1701-D are there any other similarly named locations on any of the other Enterprises?

Comment: I've been through Memory Alpha and searched by the modifiers "forward", "aft", "port" and "starboard" plus numbers (both numeral and lettered) from "one" to "thirty-five" and I can't see any canonical rooms that have a similar designation.

Comment: Did any other sci-fi flagship need a place where Space Whoopi could encourage Worf to drink prune juice? In TOS the equivalent was Scotty's quarters. In DS9 the equivalent was obviously Quark's bar, and in VOY they had Neelix's galley and Paris' holodeck programmes. Were the named the same? No. Did they fulfil the same function? Yes.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I think you have the question backwards. I'm asking about *any* location with a similar name. Those are similar places but with any old name.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - e.g. Nine Aft, Seven Port, Twelve Starboard.

Comment: [Grey 17 is Missing](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Grey_17_is_Missing)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be [that guy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=That%20Guy), but yes, there's a similarly named space on another Federation ship, specifically a room on the NCC-1701-***E*** called (I'm so sorry) "*Ten-Forward*".

This room is seen in the film *Star Trek: Insurrection* and was confirmed in Star Trek Magazine ([Vol.2 #6](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Magazine_Volume_2,_Issue_6)) as being named Ten-Forward.

[image]

> *"**Deck 10 also contains the Ten-Forward lounge** and the ship's main escape pods."*

This was also re-confirmed in several EU trek novels.

> The captain and crew of the Enterprise-E were more than worthy of their distinction, and Vaughn was certain they could handle themselves against a few Breen.
>
> [...]
>
> Although he'd assumed she would be seeking him out eventually—she'd
> already talked to everyone else on the away team — **Vaughn hadn't
> actually decided to speak to Deanna Troi until she approached him in
> Ten-Forward,** a full day after they'd left the Kamal behind. He'd been
> enjoying the feelings he'd been having, and felt protective of them,
> not sure if he wanted them analyzed. He would not have sought her out,
> in any case—he had too many secrets to ever feel entirely comfortable
> around a Betazoid, let alone someone he'd known as a Mend's child—but
> since finding the Orb, he'd also felt open to trying new things. Like
> talking to a counselor.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9 - Avatar: Book 1](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Avatar,_Book_One)</sup></sub>

Comment: Given somebody else edited in the '-D' I'm half tempted to remove it again 

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Given that there's no Ten-Forward on the [NCC-1701 Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701)), I'd say that they did you a favour

Comment: it's later renamed to the "Happy Bottom Riding Club" which was a real place (see 'The Right Stuff')